# footer is not fixed to bottom

Tags: html

```
<footer class="footer">
<!-- Copyright -->
<div class="navbar fixed-bottom my_footer">
<p class="text-center"> © 2022 Copyright: Anoop Electronics </p>
</div>
<!-- Copyright -->
</footer>
```

this footer is not fixed to the bottom. It follows when its scrolling down/up.
https://ecommerce9.pythonanywhere.com/shop/

Comment: so remove the fixed-bottom class, it will stay at bottom

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour for `position: fixed`. It breaks the element out of the flow of the page and fixes it relative to the viewport, regardless of scroll position.

Simply removing `fixed-bottom` from the footer element places the footer back in the page flow which I believe is what you are trying to achieve.